# Will all the variables be updated (through backprop+optim) w/o using tf.stop_gradient in tensorflow2.0/1.0 or with stop_gradient=False in paddlepaddle

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradient-descent, backpropagation, paddle-paddle

**If the answer is yes**, and is this true that arbitrary ops/functions/methods could be backpropagated through? Furthermore,for example, what's the gradient of scalar_y w.r.t. tensor_x in below code:

***step1:*** `scalar_y = tf.size(tensor_x)` OR `scalar_y = paddle.fluid.layers.size(tensor_x)`

***step2:*** `tensor_z = scalar_y * tensor_x`

**If the answer is no**, and then under what circumstances or in which (types of) ops will this happens, and why?

---

One more concrete example(one implementation of *DropBlock*) : **Line 34~37** in https://github.com/DHZS/tf-dropblock/blob/master/nets/dropblock.py

My question is whether it is necessary to wrap all the variables below in
**tf.stop_gradient**:

`output = inputs * mask * tf.to_float(tf.size(mask)) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)`

Anybody help?